# Is it the intended behaviour of Karpenter to record huge amount of EC2 fleet resources in AWS Config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config, karpenter

**Info:**When using Karpenter as an autoscaler in my EKS cluster, tens of thousands of entries is recorded in AWS Config with the resource type `"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::EC2Fleet"`.

**Goal:** I would like it to not do that, because the cost of AWS Config goes up disproportionally.

**What I have tried:** Running Karpenter both with and without consolidation, to see if it made a difference.

**Question**: Is there anything I can do to stop it, is my configuration bad, or is this the intended behaviour of Karpenter? If it is, I will move on to not recording those changes.

**Current Karpenter config**:

```
"apiVersion": "karpenter.sh/v1alpha5"
"kind": "Provisioner"
"metadata":
  "name": "dynamic"
"spec":
  "consolidation":
    "enabled": true
  "labels":
    "team/dynamic": "true"
  "providerRef":
    "name": "dynamic"
  "requirements":
  - "key": "karpenter.sh/capacity-type"
    "operator": "In"
    "values":
    - "spot"
    - "on-demand"
  - "key": "kubernetes.io/arch"
    "operator": "In"
    "values":
    - "arm64"
    - "amd64"
  - "key": "karpenter.k8s.aws/instance-category"
    "operator": "In"
    "values":
    - "a"
    - "c"
    - "m"
    - "r"
    - "i"
  "tags":
    "karpenter.sh/discovery": "[cluster-name]"
  "taints":
  - "effect": "NoSchedule"
    "key": "team/dynamic"
    "value": "true"
  "weight": 1
```